# How to inject Room in viewmodel using koin

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-room, koin

This is my first mvvm project with koin and I'm using Room database. I'm making network calls in viemwodel, and after fetching data from the api I want to store it in the database. Below is my class which has all the db methods like insert and delete.

```
class UserViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
   
    private val userSDAO: UserDAO
    private val userDB: AppSettingsDatabase

    init {
        userDB = AppSettingsDatabase.getAppSettingsDatabase(application.applicationContext)!!
        userDAO = userDB.userDao()
    }

    fun getAppSetting():LiveData<AppSettingsEntity>{
        return userDB.appSettingDao().getAllAppSettings()
    }

    fun deleteUser() {
        userDB.databaseWriteExecutor.execute { ->
            userDAO.deleteUser()
        }
    }
}
```

I was calling this class from activity like this

```
userViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(UserViewModel::class.java)
```

now I want to call this inside a viewmodel class where I am making the network api calls and I don't know what is the best approach to access it using koin, or any other way.I have different methods where I need database access and I have to initialize it like above in every method.

```
class SubscriptionViewModel(): BaseViewModel() {

    fun init(owner:ViewModelStoreOwner) { 
        userServiceViewModel = ViewModelProvider(owner).get(UserServiceViewModel::class.java)
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, it's a better pattern to not accessing a db object in `ViewModel`. I mean the dao should be used in a data source class, then the data source would be injected in the `ViewModel` or even better, use the data source in a repository, then inject the repository in the `ViewModel`.

After that, you must not access a `ViewModel` inside another one. They should be independent. If you want to do something with the db or api in multiple `ViewModel`s, access to them through a common repository class.

Please take a look at: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide#overview

Comment: This comment still doesn't answer the question in how to inject the actual db object into the repository

Comment: A similar question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69835118/6411857)